# Find the function which satisfies the follow properties

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis

$f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continous on $\Bbb R$.  There is $F$ a primitive of it, with the property that for every $n \in \Bbb N^*$, there is a bounded interval $I_n$ with $0\lt \vert{F(x)-f(x)}\vert\lt\frac 1n$ $\forall x \in I_n$.

$x^n$ verify the property, but how I should come with the result without guessing just working out?

Comment: Try $f(x) = e^{2x}$, $F(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{2x}$.

Comment: @ClementYung I need a rigorous proof

Comment: Well have you tried constructing this rigorous proof yourself?